# Can I show a UIAlertView as a banner (similar to push notifications) in iOS 5?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios5, uialertview, alert, banner

I am using a UIAlertView in my code in iOS5, but rather than the classic popup window with an "OK" button to exit, I'd prefer to have my alert show as a banner at the top of the screen that eventually fades away.

Is it possible to change the style of UIAlertView to resemble the iOS 5 push notification banner or does it have to be a popup window that must be dismissed manually? If not, is there any way to use the iOS5 banner notification rather than an alert notification? I don't need to send a push notification but just need to alert the user of something that happens on the server side using the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not using the SDK. You'll have to design and implement that by yourself.
Have a look at:
http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/mkinfopanel
http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/jhnotificationmanager